# Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigatorContainer' inside another.(react-native)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have error:Component Exception(Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably error. I want to navigate from LoginScreen to TabStackScreen. How can i solve this problem? please help me.

// SwitchScreen.js

```
const SwitchStack = createStackNavigator(); 
    export default function SwitchScreen() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <SwitchStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
            <SwitchStack.Screen
              name="Login"
              component={LoginScreen}
              title="Login"
            />
            <SwitchStack.Screen name="Tab" component={TabStackScreen} />
          </SwitchStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```

//TabStackScreen.js

```
const ListStack = createStackNavigator(); 

function ListStackScreen() {
  return (
    <ListStack.Navigator>
      <ListStack.Screen name=" " component={ListScreen} title="List" />
      <ListStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </ListStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function TabStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="List">
        <Tab.Screen
          name="List"
          component={ListStackScreen}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Add" component={AddScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

//App.js

```
export default class extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
  };
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false }); 
    }, 3000); 
  };
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <Loading />;
    } else {
      return <SwitchScreen />;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include your App.js file? ... or the component where you render your root-navigator

Comment: yes i'm done. please help me

Comment: Remove this `<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>` you're having around your `TabNavigator`

Comment: I deleted it now, but I stil have same error message.